# htaccess Authtype for subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, basic-authentication

I have an folder protected by htacces and I use a GET POST to know who is conected like that :

```
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Acces Restreint"
AuthType Basic
<Limit GET POST>
require valid-user
</Limit>
```

I have two users : user_1 and user_2.

Under this folder, I have different folders, let say A and B. Is it possible to restrict the access regarding the user (without putting an .htaccess in all subfolders like A and B)? 
For example, user_1 can access main/A and main/B, but user_2 can access only main/A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require valid-user` matches if any user authenticated. You can change that to `require user user_1` to require user_1 (i.e., limit access to user_1).

E.g. in the main folder you use `require valid-user` and you put another .htaccess file with `require user user_1` in folder B- Then user_2 cannot access folder B any more, but user_1 can still access both folders.

If you have more users it would be advisable to use a groups file (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_groupfile.html) - then you can use `require group X` instead of listing all users everywhere.

Instead of putting an .htaccess file into all directories, you can also define it in httpd.conf (or the file where you define your vhost) and use the Directory or Directory-Match sections there (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory). Within these sections you can also use the `require user ...` or `require valid-user` directives.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. My question was about the way to do it  without adding a htaccess in each subfolder. I have around 20 subfolders with different rights :(

Comment: You could also define this in httpd.conf using the Directory or Directory-Match sections (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory), just put the `require user ...` stuff there.

Comment: "My question was about the way to do it without adding a htaccess in each subfolder." That wasn't clear to me in the first place as you had two typos in this sentence - I just fixed that... ;)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your last sentence. I cannot change the httpd.conf on the productive server :)...